# Is it possible to make part of an HTML/CSS polyline, a bezier curve?

Tags: html, css, svg, polyline, bezier

So here is the code that I have:

```
<svg height="200" width="500">
  <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180"
            style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />
</svg>
```

which draws in the following polyline:

[image: polyline]

However, what I'm trying to achieve (in order to subsequently animate the polyline) is a polyline with an embedded bezier curve:

[image: polyline with bezier curve]

Is this even possible? If so, how do I go about creating something like this embedding the bezier curve?

Comment: If you want a bezier curve, use a `<path>` element. You can't do it with a polyline.

Comment: @RobertLongson Is it possible then to create a polyline with `<path>`??

Comment: I have no idea of SVG, but a quick search lead me to https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves

Comment: @user2230470 yes, a path is the most general shape.

Comment: @Oriol Yeah, I came across lots of information like that when I was searching. I don't want just a single curve with a couple nodes, though. I want a polyline (or path?) with many, many nodes. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @RobertLongson Alright, I'll have to do some reading. Thanks! :D

Comment: @RobertLongson **So how come this (http://s24.postimg.org/d208bgadh/path.png) happens if I try to implement C (curveto) or S (smooth curveto)? And how come, if I remove C and or S and instead use L (lineto) like all of the other nodes, I get this (http://s27.postimg.org/s7k8ehu1f/pathwithoutcs.png)??? I'm dumbfounded. Thanks in advance<3

Comment: @RobertLongson NM. Figured it out. Was missing the control points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course? Just use a `<path d="...">` instead of a `<polyline>`. The path element can draw anything a polyline can, as well as curves, arcs, etc, so just draw the lines you need, connected with either quadratic or cubic beziers wherever you need them, and there you go.

More information everywhere on the internet, but the two obvious places to start would be the [MDN article on paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) and of course [the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).